# Hanging drywall on 2x2 ceiling joints 16 on center

Tags: drywall, ceiling, hanging

I want to replace the fiber tiles with drywall. The ceiling is made up of 2x2 16 on center, I plan to use 12' long pieces less seams. What thickness of drywall is safe to use.
Thank you for any information you can provide.

Comment: You have 2x2 ceiling joists?  Are you sure?  Or are you talking about 2x2 furring?

Comment: Is that 2x2 furings on ceiling joists?

Comment: If they are ceiling ‘joists’ (as opposed to perpendicular furring), what’s the clear span?

Comment: And if you specified the size of the ceiling, we could offer opinions about 12’ vs 8’ sheets.

Answer (score 2):

ASTM C840 specifies about everything for by-the-book drywall. For 16" support spacing and insulation supported by the drywall, Table 2 prescribes a minimum thickness of 1/2". Without insulation supported by the drywall, it's 3/8" minimum thickness. The long edge of the drywall sheets must run perpendicular to the support framing.